# Removing just one Row in table - SpringBoot & Java & Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, html-table, thymeleaf, removechild

New to Spring-boot and Java and Thymeleaf...Trying to make it so the trash button deletes only one row in this table. Right now it if any trash button is clicked, all table rows are deleted.
I ran the debugger and my controller is picking up the rowId for whichever button is clicked, so not sure why it's deleting all rows and not just the one. Any ideas?

[image]

```java
//code that loads form and table (table is made up of Ams360Policies)
  @GetMapping("/directBind")
  public String getDirectBind(Model model){
        List<String> businessAgencies = new ArrayList<String>();
        businessAgencies.add("Personal");
        businessAgencies.add("Commercial");
        businessAgencies.add("Life");
        businessAgencies.add("Benefits");
        businessAgencies.add("Health");
        businessAgencies.add("Non P and C");
        model.addAttribute("businessAgencies", businessAgencies);

        DirectBind directBind = new DirectBind();

        List<Ams360Policy> ams360Policies = new ArrayList();
        Ams360Policy ams360Policy = new Ams360Policy();
        ams360Policies.add(ams360Policy);
        model.addAttribute("ams360Policies", ams360Policy);

        List<String> billTypeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        billTypeList.add("Direct Bill");
        billTypeList.add("Agency Bill");
        model.addAttribute("billTypeList", billTypeList);
        ams360Policy.setBillTypeOptions(billTypeList);

        List<String> businessAgencyList = new ArrayList<String>();
        directBind.setBusinessAgencyList(businessAgencyList);

        model.addAttribute("directBind", directBind);

        return "directBind";
    }


//code to add a Row to table

    @RequestMapping(value="/directBind", params="addPolicy")
    public String addPolicy(final DirectBind directBind, Model model){
        List<Ams360Policy> ams360Policies =  directBind.getAms360Policies();
        Ams360Policy ams360Policy = new Ams360Policy();
        ams360Policies.add(ams360Policy);
        model.addAttribute("ams360Policies", ams360Policies);


        List<String> billTypeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        billTypeList.add("Direct Bill");
        billTypeList.add("Agency Bill");
        model.addAttribute("billTypeList", billTypeList);
        ams360Policy.setBillTypeOptions(billTypeList);

        List<String> businessAgencyList = new ArrayList<String>();
        directBind.setBusinessAgencyList(businessAgencyList);

        return "directBind";
    }

//code to Remove row of table

@RequestMapping(value = "/directBind", params="removeRow")
public String removeRow(final DirectBind directBind, final HttpServletRequest req, Model model){
    final Integer rowId = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("removeRow"));
    List<Ams360Policy> ams360Policies =  directBind.getAms360Policies();
    model.addAttribute("ams360Policies", ams360Policies);
    directBind.setAms360Policies(ams360Policies);

    Ams360Policy ams360Policy = new Ams360Policy();
    List<String> billTypeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    billTypeList.add("Direct Bill");
    billTypeList.add("Agency Bill");
    model.addAttribute("billTypeList", billTypeList);
    ams360Policy.setBillTypeOptions(billTypeList);

    List<String> businessAgencyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    directBind.setBusinessAgencyList(businessAgencyList);

    directBind.getAms360Policies().remove(1);
    model.addAttribute("directBind", directBind);
    return "directBind";
}
```

```html
//html code for table 
<div>
  <h4 style="display: inline;">AMS360 Policy Setup</h4>
  <input type="submit" formnovalidate="formnovalidate"  name="addPolicy" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem;" value="+"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <hr/>

            <table class="table table-striped AMSTable" data-classes="table-no-bordered" data-striped="true" data-show-columns="true" data-pagination="true">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Policy Number</th>
                    <th>Policy Term Start Date</th>
                    <th>Policy Term End Date</th>
                    <th>Line of Coverage</th>
                    <th>Parent Company</th>
                    <th>Writing Company</th>
                    <th>Bill Type</th>
                    <th>Quote Premium</th>
                    <th>Commission</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr id="newPolicyRow" th:each="ams360Policy, stat : ${ams360Policies}">
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].policyNumber}"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].policyTermDateStart}"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].policyTermDateEnd}"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].lineOfCoverage}"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].parentCompany}"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].writingCompany}"/></td>
                    <td id="billTypeCell">
                        <div  th:each="billType : ${billTypeList}">
                            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].billTypeOptions}" th:value="${billType}"/>
                            <label th:text="${billType}" id="billTypeLabel"></label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].quotePremium}"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].commission}"/></td>
                    <td class="text-right"> <button type="submit" name="removeRow" th:value="${stat.index}" class="btn btn-danger" ><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

When I debug I get the following...
[image]

Comment: could you please print the list : directBind.getAms360Policies() inside removeRow() method ?

Comment: @IssamEL-GUERCH Sorry, really new to Java, it wont let me throw in         System.out.print(directBind.getAms360Policies()); to the method... is there a better way to print the list?  When I put that in and run it, I get the following error: java.lang.NullPointerException: null  and [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

Comment: you get NullPointerException because directBind have null value, its alredy empty or getAms360Policies() return null value, check your variables

Comment: @IssamEL-GUERCH I am confused because when I debug, I am getting an error of cannot find local variable and at the same time, it is showing everything correctly. I will post a photo... any idea why the ams360Policies issue is happening?

Comment: So I'm very close to solving this so I updated my removeRow method. I have it working hard coded, but any idea how I can get it to remove a row based on which one is clicked on, when no rows have index ids because this is not connected to a database?

Answer (score 0):

```html
//html code for table 
<div>
  <h4 style="display: inline;">AMS360 Policy Setup</h4>
  <input type="submit" formnovalidate="formnovalidate"  name="addPolicy" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem;" value="+"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <hr/>

            <table class="table table-striped AMSTable" data-classes="table-no-bordered" data-striped="true" data-show-columns="true" data-pagination="true">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Policy Number</th>
                    <th>Policy Term Start Date</th>
                    <th>Policy Term End Date</th>
                    <th>Line of Coverage</th>
                    <th>Parent Company</th>
                    <th>Writing Company</th>
                    <th>Bill Type</th>
                    <th>Quote Premium</th>
                    <th>Commission</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr id="newPolicyRow" th:each="ams360Policy, stat : ${ams360Policies}">
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].policyNumber}"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].policyTermDateStart}"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].policyTermDateEnd}"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].lineOfCoverage}"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].parentCompany}"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].writingCompany}"/></td>
                    <td id="billTypeCell">
                        <div  th:each="billType : ${billTypeList}">
                            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].billTypeOptions}" th:value="${billType}"/>
                            <label th:text="${billType}" id="billTypeLabel"></label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].quotePremium}"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].commission}"/></td>
                    <td class="text-right"> <button type="submit" name="removeRow" th:value="${stat.index}" class="btn btn-danger" ><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).